# Use Streams to return Boolean if all the List values in a Map are empty/not-empty

Tags: java, java-stream

Given a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) mapping a String to a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), is there a way to use [Java Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html) to return a Boolean where TRUE means one or more list had elements? If all lists in the map were empty, return FALSE.

```
Map< String , List<String> > map = …
```

Can use of Streams replace this conventional code?

```
// See if any diffs were found. Loop through the Map, look at each List of diffs to see if non-empty.
boolean anyElementsInAnyList = false;
for (List<String> list : map.values () ) {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        anyElementsInAnyList = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Note that we can break out of the examination after the first finding. No need to examine all the Map values (all the Lists). Would be nice if, for efficiency, the Stream could do the same stop-work-on-first-finding (a “short-circuiting” operation).

Comment: Do you mean this java-stream ? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

Comment: Any reason for using `Boolean` instead of `boolean` in you loop?

Comment: @Holger `Boolean` preferred over `boolean, because I am an Object-Oriented kind of person. And because when doing further work such as representing values in a UI framework such as *Vaadin*, I will likely need objects rather than primitives.

Comment: Code doesn’t become more object-oriented when you write `Boolean` instead of `boolean`. It just opens a new error source, as a `Boolean` reference can be `null` and the `==` operator doesn’t do what you might intend. Besides that, this code still is the same imperative loop. By the way, what made you answer this four year old question right now?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## `Stream::allMatch`

In Java 8 you can check that not all lists are empty.

```
 boolean anyNonEmpty = !map.values().stream().allMatch(List::isEmpty);
```

Notice that [`Stream::allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) is a [short-circuiting terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps). So the stream is efficient, not running any longer than need be.

Comment: Interesting to see the converse of the code in [answer by rgettman](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35282464/642706), using `allMatch` versus `anyMatch`. Looks to me like this approach here cannot take advantage of a “short-circuiting” operation. So it is not as efficient as rgettman’s which will short-circuit.

Comment: @BasilBourque The `allMatch` method is also short-circuiting.

Comment: @Basil Bourque: don’t go by the method name, go by [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-): “*This is a short-circuiting terminal operation.*”

Answer (score 27):

Use [the `anyMatch` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) that finds if any element of the stream matches a `Predicate`.  Here, your predicate is that the entry's value (the list) is not empty.

```
boolean anyNonEmpty = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .anyMatch(entry -> !entry.getValue().isEmpty());
```

Comment: @hotkey You should have just commented that I could replace `entrySet` with `values` and in the predicate go straight to `!list.isEmpty`.

Comment: Good, thanks! The doc says this method is a [short-circuiting terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps). So this Stream should have some of the efficiency of not checking all values in the Map. Apparently we get this benefit even working in parallel (multi-threaded) according to [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27235839/642706).

Comment: @rgettman: you could replace `entrySet` with `values` and in the predicate go straight to `!list.isEmpty`     ;-). By the way, even the question’s code already uses `values()`.

Answer (score -2):

```
int size = Map.entrySet().stream()
                           .map(entry -> entry.getValue())
                           .flatMap(list -> list.stream())
                           .size();
if(size==0)
  return Boolean.False;
else
  return Boolean.True;
```

This code is a simple one this may help for your work .

Comment: Down-votes? Please leave your critique comments along with your vote. This is a solid answer, educational, with an interesting alternative approach. Not the best fit for this Question’s scenario, but could be quite useful to other readers with a slightly different scenario.

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but there are some obvious things to criticize. First, the use of `Map` (easy to confuse with the type of that name) instead of the correct variable name `map`, then, it makes no sense to stream over `entrySet()` just to map to the values in the next step, especially as the question already hints at the existence of `values()` that you can stream over in the first place. Further, there is no `size()` method in `Stream` and even if it existed, it was a waste of resources here, as counting all elements can’t be short-circuiting in general. Not to speak about `return size==0;`…