# Detect if a Hashmap with Java Optional has empty values or not?

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, option-type

I want to find out if the `HashMap` has all its values empty or not. What is the best way to do it other than having to check the value in every entry in the map?

```
HashMap<Long, Optional<Long>> aMap = new HashMap<>();

aMap.put(new Long(55), Optional.empty());
aMap.put(new Long(66), Optional.empty());
aMap.put(new Long(77), Optional.empty());
aMap.put(new Long(99), Optional.empty());
```

Comment: There is *no* way of doing it other than checking every entry in the map, but there are various ways of doing that. @SotiriosDelimanolis  Solution in that link will not work for `Optional`.

Comment: @EJP Why wouldn't it? An `allMatch` with `Optional::isPresent`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't see that solution in the link, and the question clearly specifies 'other than checking every value'.

Comment: @EJP Am I misreading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35282505/438154)?

Comment: Or more duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304129/how-to-check-if-all-elements-of-java-collection-match-some-condition

Comment: This seems like a bad use of `Optional`. A map should just not have values instead of having placeholder "empty" ones.

Comment: @chrylis I don't think that's necessary true, if you've ever had a hashmap with a null value, this is probably a better way than checking null.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for this comment. I was originally using 2 lists of equal sizes and was suggested to put them in a map. But i know the fact that the values are going to be always with all entries or all empty. So a map with Optional does not really fit my actual use case, would not have realized this until reading your comment, although it was good learning how to check all empty values:)

Comment: As a side note, you should never use `new Long(…)`. The preferred way is `Long.valueOf(…)` or just use a plain long value like `55L` and let the compiler use autoboxing, which will call `Long.valueOf(55L)` under the hood.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use java 8 stream's API.

Using [allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```java
boolean allEmpty = aMap.values()
    .stream()
    .allMatch(opt -> !opt.isPresent());
```

Or using [noneMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#noneMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
boolean allEmpty = aMap.values()
    .stream()
    .noneMatch(Optional::isPresent);
```

An important thing to note from the documentation, is that both methods are 'short-circuiting terminal operations'

> This is a short-circuiting terminal operation.

This means that the method doesn't need to evaluate the entire stream, when it founds the first match in `noneMatch` or the first mismatch in `allMatch` it returns immediatly.

Answer (score -6):

There is *no* way of doing it other than checking the value in every entry in the map (of course stopping when you find a non-null), but there are various ways of doing that, and no doubt many answers showing how will be posted.

Comment: I think this should've been a comment as it doesn't _literally_ answer the question rather direct towards it.

Comment: @PankajSinghal Sometimes the answer is just 'no'. There isn't a way to literally answer the question as posed.